# Tkinter GUI Composition

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I've just started programming in Tkinter and my question is why does the 'master' method work without needing to assigned an instance of the Tk() class?
In other Tkinter projects I've seen they have a variable that takes Tk() as its parameters? i.e master = Tk()

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you assign a instance of Tk():

```
root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
```

Here, root is an instance of Tk() and the second parameter of the "**init**"
And you give it the name of "master" in you "**init**"
No?

Comment: I figured that was it but I wasn't 100% sure. Thanks for the help and sorry the trivial question.

Comment: No problem! Choose the answer and give-it a +1! ;-)